# ng-table 'select-multiple' filter is not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I am working on angular's ng-table, what i am trying to do is applying filters on ng-table for field(Types), i have more fields to apply the filter but for now i want to make filter work on one field then rest, plunker below, By selecting more than one choice from the select menu, only those records should display in the table. But for some reason filter is not working, any idea why.

Also one more thing i want is get the selected filter from ng-table to a object in the controller.

Any help is much appreciated.

Followed this [example](http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-customize-algorithm)

Comment: Plunker here : https://plnkr.co/edit/XOL6NSVV2iBsYZmad5eO?p=preview

Comment: Could any one give a try on this?

Answer (score 0):

There two errors in your code:

1. html: change `<tr ng-repeat="i in dataObject">` to `<tr ng-repeat="i in $data">`
2. js: change `dataset:$scope.tableData` to `dataset:$scope.dataObject`

besides the 2 changes, and 1 more change:
3. `$scope.types=[
      {id:'Maintenance',title:'Maintenance'},
      {id:'Modification',title:'Modification'},
      ];`